# For which values of $p$ is the Markov chain recurrent? ( sort of a RW with two steps forward and one back)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

I have a process with indices in $\mathbb{Z}$ with the following transition probabilities: $P(i,i+2)=p$ and $P(i,i-1)=1-p$, with $p\in(0,1)$, i.e. with probability $p$ I take two steps forward and with probability $1-p$ I go one step backwards. I have to determine for which values of $p$ this Markov chain is recurrent.

My idea was to compute the powers of the transition matrix (it´s easy to notice that the chain has period 3, so one is interested in the diagonal of the matrices $P^{3n}$), then check with the criterion saying that the chain is recurrent iff $\sum_{n}P^n(i,i)=\infty$. However, the computations seem cumbersome and I was wondering if anyone has a better idea on how to do this. A reference (on this process) would also be extremely appreciated.

Comment: An easy test for recurrence of a random walk is the Chung-Fuchs Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chung%E2%80%93Fuchs_theorem ): which, in part, says that in one dimension the walk is recurrent if and only if the mean step size is 0.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I did not know this result, but as far as I can see, the equivalence is not exactly as you described it. Instead, the walk is recurrent iff a weak version of the law of large numbers holds for the random walk. This happens, in particular, if the mean step size is 0.

Comment: Not sure where you saw that version of the theorem, but a 1-d walk on the integers has it that the walk is recurrent if mean step size is $0$. In your case, iff $p=1/3$. Here is another reference: https://books.google.com.au/books?id=UELNGL9bXSQC&pg=PA177&lpg=PA177&dq=%22chung-fuchs%22+mean&source=bl&ots=t1TyTc8V3k&sig=HNeUHNIcKBw6oOQRmq9rAkN7i-s&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjww4GMsaTKAhUS5WMKHdzyApIQ6AEINzAH#v=onepage&q=%22chung-fuchs%22%20mean&f=false

Comment: @CameliaDumitrescu I think you mean $P(i,i-1)=1-p$, not $P(i-1,i)=1-p$.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, yes, thank you. I corrected the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see why for $p \neq 1/3$ the process is transient, just apply Law of Large Numbers.

Let $X_i \in \{ -1, 2 \}$ where $X_i = -1 $(with probability $1-p$) and $X_i = 2$ (with probability $p$). Then, we are talking about the process $(S_n)_n$ where $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $, right?

Well, we have $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 3p-1$, thus, using independence of $X_i$'s, Law of Large Numbers implies that

$$
\frac{S_n}{n} \longrightarrow 3p-1
$$
almost surely. This means that your process has a drift to the right or the left (depending on $p$). This also implies that if you start the chain at zero, for example, you will visit it only a finite number of times and since the chain is irreducible, you have that the only chance of being recurrent is if $p=1/3$.

For $p=1/3$ you can apply similar argument employed to prove that the symmetric random walk is recurrent.

Hope this can help!

Comment: Thank you. Yes, indeed, this is the correct answer, I´m convinced. I had previously made some mistakes in my computations/reasoning. (I was looking for a more elementary proof, i.e. without the law of large numbers, but it´s definitely a convincing argument. In the mean time, I managed to find the type of proof I wanted.) Thank you again!

Comment: No problem. What kind of solution do you look for?